# Pandas Add suffix of count to all groups

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I've added a category to.  Now I want to add a count to consecutive values in the groups.

So the data looks like this

| P1 | P2 | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 | A |
| 99 | 42 | A |
| 55 | 67 | B |
| 55 | 100 | C |
| 55 | 120 | C |
| 12 | 34 | A |
| 99 | 42 | A |
| 12 | 34 | A |

I want to add a count of consecutive number of elements in a group like

| P1 | P2 | group | group_element_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 | A | A1 |
| 99 | 42 | A | A2 |
| 55 | 67 | B | B1 |
| 55 | 100 | C | C1 |
| 55 | 120 | C | C2 |
| 12 | 34 | A | A1 |
| 99 | 42 | A | A2 |
| 12 | 34 | A | A3 |

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "p1": [12, 99, 55, 55,55,12,99,12],
  "p2": [34, 42, 67, 100,120, 34,42,34],
  "group":['A','A','B','C','C','A','A','A']
}

#load data into a DataFrame object:
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head()
```

This is not the real data and the groups are added by something like this
df["group"] = pd.Categorical(p1, categories = grades.values(), ordered=True)

Comment: @mozway - Are you sure dupe is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create consecutive groups by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and add to `group` values:

```
s = df.groupby(df['group'].ne(df['group'].shift()).cumsum()).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
df['group_element_count'] = df['group'].add(s)
print (df)
   P1   P2 group group_element_count
0  12   34     A                  A1
1  99   42     A                  A2
2  55   67     B                  B1
3  55  100     C                  C1
4  55  120     C                  C2
5  12   34     A                  A1
6  99   42     A                  A2
7  12   34     A                  A3
```

How it working:

```
print (df.assign(group=df['group'].ne(df['group'].shift()).cumsum(),
                 counter = s,
                 group_element_count = df['group'].add(s)))

   P1   P2  group counter group_element_count
0  12   34      1       1                  A1
1  99   42      1       2                  A2
2  55   67      2       1                  B1
3  55  100      3       1                  C1
4  55  120      3       2                  C2
5  12   34      4       1                  A1
6  99   42      4       2                  A2
7  12   34      4       3                  A3
```

Comment: It works!  Thanks so much.  I have no idea how it works though.  Would u care to explain?

Comment: @newoptionz - Sure, give me some time.

Comment: @newoptionz - added helper columns with intermediate results, if necessary explain more, let me know.